# having a php page send an email

Tags: php

This question should have a simple, simple answer, but I just can't seem to get it working. Here's the scenario:

I created a php page -> this one: http://adianl.ca/pages/member_application.php.  Once the form is completed, it proceeds to http://adianl.ca/pages/member_application_action.php, puts the data into a MySQL db, & thanks the user for their interest.  Anyway, the form works perfectly, except for one little thing: whenever someone fills out that form, I want an email to be sent to sbeattie@adianl.ca, informing them that the form was filled out, & the email would include the form components.  The problem is, I can NOT get an email to be sent to that address, or any address truth be told.  Having a php page send an email should be a simple thing to do, but it's really baffling me.

Can anyone help me with this?  This particular problem has been troubling me since yesterday, & if anyone can help me with this...man, thank you soooooo much.

JP

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP 
$mail->Host = "mail.adianl.ca"; // SMTP server $mail->From = "webadmin@adianl.ca";       
$mail->FromName = "Web Administration [ADIANL]";       
$mail->AddAddress("sbeattie@adianl.ca"); 
$mail->AddCC("justinwparsons@gmail.com"); the #messageBody variable is just a string
```

Comment: Show the code where you're sending the email.

Comment: It can be a lot of things, you need to show the code you're using to send the emails and the config parameters associated

Comment: $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.adianl.ca"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = "webadmin@adianl.ca";
$mail->FromName = "Web Administration [ADIANL]";
$mail->AddAddress("sbeattie@adianl.ca");
$mail->AddCC("justinwparsons@gmail.com");

the #messageBody variable is just a string

Comment: Each web server may have different configurations regarding sending of email, including authentication or disabling of the php's built-in mail() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the email sent using the server's sendmail client, you can use [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

If you want it to use another mail server, there are extensions to connect to an SMTP server. I use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

If mail doesn't work, it could be that the server is not set up to send email, or it could be that the mail server is rejecting emails sent from php, amongst other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

this code can also be used to email in php so have a look, you can find many more examples of emailing in php look around

```
?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
```